# Background image at 100% of window (and resizes with it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

#### Duplicate of:

[Stretch and Scale CSS Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)
[How do I stretch a background image to cover the entire HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235855/how-do-i-stretch-a-background-image-to-cover-the-entire-html-element)
[background image doesn’t stretch full page width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645279/background-image-doesnt-stretch-full-page-width)

I've got a webpage background image, which needs to be displayed fully at 100% of the window's size. If the window is resized, the image needs to resize with it, to stay at 100%.

CSS does not allow you to set the sizes of the background image, only the way it repeats. (but I want it stretched)

I assume jQuery is the safest and quickest way of realizing this, to overcome browser-incompatibleness. Or can this be done quickly with regular javascript?

Comment: alltough it's a duplicate, I like this question's accepted answer better than the ones from the earlier questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stretch a background image to cover the entire HTML element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235855/how-do-i-stretch-a-background-image-to-cover-the-entire-html-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This link might interest you:

[How Do you Stretch a Background Image in a Web Page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm)

Comment: Alltough it uses conditional <!--[if IE 6]> stuff, it does the job with only CSS. Nice.