# Full width background inside a div

Tags: html, css

So, i have:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="full-width">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo img-responsive" />
            </a>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li><a href="">Moden Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Prices</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Demonstration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside a `<div class="wrapper">`, that has the `width:1100px;`. So the question is if i can somehow make the `div class="full-width"` with a full width background... Because it stops at the `.wrapper`'s margins.

I tried this method, but it doesn't work:

```
.full-width {
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: a live Fiddle will be helpful. also. did you meant `.wrapper`s padding?

Comment: If you plan to support only modern browsers your task is quite simple using `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874372/background-image-at-100-of-window-and-resizes-with-it

Comment: Where do you want to place `.full-width`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your whole code but here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/sjk3G/)

```
.full-width {
  background: #333;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could add `left:0px;` and try it again. You could also try using a negative margin or a width over 100%. I hope, that helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the size of the background using

```
background-size {
 Xpx Ypx;
}
```

or you can try giving a background to full-width's container.

Answer (score -1):

Set your css to `max-width:100%; max-height:100%;`

Also, read http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images